# calling a method on button click inside a webmethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i am working on a "webform" which has three button cancel,save ,and save and email.
the code is running fine with cancel and save button. but on save and email button i am making a "webmethod" which save the form values on to the another page and inside that webMethod , i want to keep a check that if "save and email" button was clicked then call another method names as "sendEmail".

Any suggestion how can i call another method  for only "save and email" button inside a webmethod.

```
<input id="SaveEntry" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
<input id="ApprovalButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save and Email" />
```

Ajax call:

```
$("#ApprovalButton").click(function () {
$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "checking.aspx/AddCashBook",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: JSON.stringify(""),
                        success: function (msg) {
                            $('#AddEntry').modal('toggle')
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: You are already calling the webmethod. What you want to do now ?

Comment: actually webmethod is called on both "save" and "save and  email " button, but i want now to check if the "save and email" button is pressed then call another method that will send the email

Comment: Have you considered using a parameter?

Comment: @stuartd i do not have idea of that . i am new to asp.net

Comment: You can use jQuery's `then` to perform further actions when the AJAX call returns. But you would be better having two web methods, one for each action (and the "& email" one callers the other first). Two HTTP round trips will not make things more efficient and opens up the possibility of just the second request failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you call same `webmethod` from both buttons. You need to pass a paramter `sendEmail` to `webmethod` which will tell you to either send email or not.

```
$("#ApprovalButton").click(function () {
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "checking.aspx/AddCashBook",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ sendEmail: true }),
                    success: function (msg) {
                        $('#AddEntry').modal('toggle')
                    }
                });
```

And in webmethod you will do this

```
[WebMethod]
public static string UpdateDB(bool sendEmail)
{
  if(sendEmail)
  //call function to send email.
}
```

Now when you will call same method from second button pass `false` to `webmethod` from ajax.

Comment: many thanks ... it worked for me :)

Comment: Welcome glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

In your Code Behind...

```
//Setup a string that will call a button click event
var BtnSendAndSaveClick =  "document.getElementById('"
                                  + ApprovalButton.ClientID.ToString() + "')"
                                  + ".click();";

//Call the other button
SaveEntry.Attributes.Add("OnClick", BtnSendAndSaveClick );
```

Comment: i do not want to call another button , but i want to call a method